# Designing A Constant-Time Algorithm For A Function

Tags: algorithm, constant-time

This question just went over my head:

A function G(m) is defined as below:

a)  If m <= 100 then G(m) = G(G(m + 11))

b)  If  m > 100 then G(m) =  m – 10

According to above question, how do I design a constant-time algorithm that calculates G(m)?

Comment: Maybe dynamic programming? Store the results of m = 1 to 100 in an array. Thus, calculating G(m <= 100) will be constant time. G(m > 100) will always be constant time.

Comment: can `m` be negative or zero?

Comment: We shouldn't be doing your homework for you. However I will give you a really big hint in that you can use basic arithmetic and discrete reasoning to assume that for <= 100 you return `m + ((floor((101 - m)/11) + 1) * 11) - 10` without any iteration required. Because the other case is also an O(1) operation you get at most O(1). Edit2: too many mistakes. there. fixed

Comment: I actually didn't expect you to complete my homework. I just wanted to explain me what is actually being asked. Edit: Even if there are iterations, the time complexity would still be O(1) as the loop will run for a limited time. Is this correct?

Comment: @MananTyagi: It forms an AP for all the values of `m`. When I simplify, it all ends up at 91. No matter what the values of `m` are, you will end up at G(101) ultimately and this evaluates to 91. Hence, `G(m)` = 91 for all values of `m` here.

Comment: well if you're really asking for an approach, it depends. Some cases might require dynamic programming. This case just requires finding a closed form of the recursive function G(m) when m <= 100. Personally, if the function is simple for the recursion (in this case simple addition) I look for a closed form of that for the bounds given first, then attack it using other approaches usually mentioned in algorithms/discrete maths books with dynamic programming being my last resort.

Comment: @MananTyagi btw your last statement is incorrect. Even if there were a lower bound, the number of recursive calls to G varies. Since we must assume we will never know for sure what `m` is we can only say that the run time is loosely bound by O(L) where L=floor((100-m)/11). Since L varies, this is not a constant running time.

Comment: @CodeHunter Can you please explain how it will always end up at 91, no matter what values we take?

Comment: @MananTyagi: If you keep solving for values of `m`, say 0, then G(0) = G(G(11)); then G(11) = G(G(22)) and so on. You will reach some point where `m` crosses 100. Then you can find some Integer value for that G(m). On trying to solve it again and again, you will eventually end up at G(101) = 91. You just need to solve it for `m` = 0 to 10 only. After that, vaues will repeat which will point that eventually you are gonna end up at 91.

Comment: it would be cool if this reduced to a single value, however you can test the hypothesis quickly by doing G(5) to see if it holds. It doesn't hold, but it's better for you to work it out and see what it equals and why it doesn't reduce to single value.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant time"? It's easy to write a function that performs O(1) arithmetic operations to compute the function (indeed, almost any implementation will do this), and it's relatively easy to perform exactly two arithmetic operations no matter the input. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Well G(1000) != G(999) != 91, so the function definitely does not always return 91 (although it does always return 91 for m<=100).

Comment: @CorvusCrypto: I do get G(5) evaluated finally to 91. G(5) will ultimately get to G(93) which gets to G(104) which will get to 94. Hence, G(93) = G(94) and so on until it reaches G(100) which will be G(111) and hence, G(111) will be G(101). Hence, G(100) = G(101) = 91. Please try again yourself if you don't get what I stated here. Also, the algorithm is required only for values less than 100. For `m`>100, it will anyways be direct calculation.

Comment: @CodeHunter ah I see what's getting yall. so basically in this case, after you reach the case where m > 100 recursion ends. There are no more calls to G.

Comment: @CorvusCrypto: exactly. So, for all cases `m`<=100, no matter what is `m`, it is always 91. For m>100, we know it is always `m-10` anyways. So, again, constant time. I don't know why people downvoted my approach!
:D

Comment: @PaulHankin: Yes. I forgot to mention that `m>100` case earlier. I got pre-occupied with all those recursions earlier actually! But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I can write some pseudocode for you both to see how this question is related to code: `G(m) => {if (m <= 100) { return G(m + 11) } else { return (m - 10) }}`

Comment: ah wow no you guys are right. Sorry I had missed the extra G(G(...)). Yeah the extra G() call makes it a constant. ops haha. sorry @CodeHunter

Comment: @CorvusCrypto: nevermind. I deleted my answer anyways in order to not attract more downvotes on that!

Comment: I'd say this shouldn't get an answer tbh. Regardless of my correctness or yours, both cases are easily analyzable, reducible, and trivial to test. even in light of our arguments it was enough for this person to finish their homework by themselves using their own head.

Comment: @CorvusCrypto Man, I didn't get what I asked for. I need the algorithm, not the mathematical induction proof. I am pretty new to all these things, which makes it tough to understand. So it would be nice if you could give the algorithm and describe it's functionality. And btw, this is not my homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (b) part can obviously be computed in constant time, assuming `m` fits in an integer variable.

The tricky part the problem is asking to prove is that the (a) part is constant. Then the `O(1)` time follows. That can be done using mathematical induction or in some other way.

The inductive proof follows.

First observe that `G(101)` is equal to 101 - 10 = 91 by definition.

For `90 <= n <= 100` it holds that `G(n) = G(G(n + 11))`, where `n + 11 > 100`. Therefore `G(n)` it is equal to `G(n + 11 - 10) = G(n+1)`, which is 91.

From this, the the ten equations `G(91 - 1) = 91`, `G(91 - (1 - 1)) = 91`, ..., `G(91 - (1 - 10)) = 91` are all true. This is the base for the general induction.

The inductive step: assume that `G(91 - i) = 91`, `G(91 - (i - 1)) = 91`, ..., `G(91 - (i - 10)) = 91` is true for all numbers `i` from 1 up to a certain bound.

Then `G(91 - (i + 1)) = G(G(91 - i - 1 + 11)) = G(G(91 - (i - 10)))`. From the base step, we know that `G(91 - (i - 10)) = 91`. Plugging this in the equation above, we get `G(91)`, which is also already known to be 91. From this it follows that the assumption is true for `i+1` as well.

Consequently, `G(91 - n)` is equal to 91 for all `n >= 1`. The induction is proven.

An example of the constant-time algorithm for computing `G` in Python:

```
def G(m):
   if m > 100:
      return m - 10
   else:
      return 91
```